# Can I tell the R plyr package to work in parallel by default?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, default, plyr

I'm doing some analysis something like this:

```
library(plyr)
input.files <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt")
input.data <- llply(input.files, load.file, .parallel=TRUE)
step.one.results <- llply(input.data, step.one, .parallel=TRUE)
step.two.results <- llply(step.one.results, step.two, .parallel=TRUE)
...
step.N.results <- llply(`step.N-1.results`, step.N, .parallel=TRUE)
...
```

Is there any way to make all the plyr functions parallel by default, so I don't always have to specify `.parallel=TRUE` for each step?

Comment: In addition to the solution below, it looks like there's a function called `set.defaults` in the `diversitree` package that can do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
library(Defaults)
setDefaults(llply, .parallel=TRUE)
```

You'd have to `setDefaults` on every function for which you want to change the default formals.  You can put this in your .Rprofile if you like.

You can also mess with the formals directly.  e.g.
`formals(llply)$.parallel <- TRUE` should work.

Comment: Just FYI, it looks like the Defaults package is no longer available on CRAN, so you'll have to mess with the formals directly.

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55302390/5968131):

As the [Defaults](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/) package is no longer available from CRAN, you can use [default](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/default/).

As an example:

```r
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
default::default(unlist) <- list(use.names = FALSE)
unlist(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3

unlist <- default::reset_default(unlist)
unlist(x)
#> a b c 
#> 1 2 3
```

Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks for your input! Unfortunately [stack overflow's policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers) is that answers should provide a solution even if the link gets removed. Please edit your question accordingly, or use a comment instead. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! According to your request, I have lazily copied my answer from the related question. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yup! As long as your answer makes sense even without the link, it's all good.