# Change default arguments of an R function at runtime

Tags: r, reflection

Is it possible to change the default values of formal parameters in an R function at runtime?

Let's assume, we have the function

```
f <- function(x=1) { 
    ...
}
```

can I somehow change the default value of x from 1 to, say, 2?

Thanks in advance,
Sven

Comment: An interesting question, but it sounds a bit dangerous. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to implement a VM for R, therefore I need to know whether function signatures can be assumed to be immutable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895811/can-i-tell-the-r-plyr-package-to-work-in-parallel-by-default/9895903#9895903

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: 2020-12-13

> This method is no longer available

Yes, the [Defaults](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults) package allows you to do this.

Comment: I found another way to accomplish this task:

    formals(f) = pairlist(x=1)

Comment: @SvenHager: that's essentially what Defaults does, and you might want to use `alist` instead of `list` or `pairlist`.

Comment: Cool.  I might use this to change paste( , sep=" ") to paste( , sep="").  (Yes, I know about paste0 in R 2.15.0)

Comment: @KevinWright: be careful doing that with widely-used support functions like `paste`.  You may break things that will be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: It looks like `Defaults` is no longer available from CRAN.  You can still do this using the `formals` function, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895811/can-i-tell-the-r-plyr-package-to-work-in-parallel-by-default/9895903#9895903

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (shown in a different [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895811/can-i-tell-the-r-plyr-package-to-work-in-parallel-by-default/)) is to use the `formals` function, e.g.:

`formals(f) <- 2`

Comment: This errors using R 4.3.2. You should set the value explicitly with `formals(f)$x <- 2`.

Answer (score 1):

As the [Defaults](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/) package is no longer available from CRAN, you can use [default](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/default/).

As an example:

```r
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
default::default(unlist) <- list(use.names = FALSE)
unlist(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3

unlist <- default::reset_default(unlist)
unlist(x)
#> a b c 
#> 1 2 3
```

Created on 2019-03-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same argument wrapping for the `packagefinder` library which has an alias of `fp()` pointing to `findPackage()`. I tried all sorts of methods, including using *`formals()`*, but in the end, the only thing that worked for me were the following 3 variations:

```r
#--------------------------------------
# packagefinder
#--------------------------------------
# fp = findPackage
# Set default to use: 
#   fp(... , display = "console", return.df = TRUE)
#--------------------------------------
fp <- function(...) {
  packagefinder::fp(..., display="console", return.df=TRUE)
}

fp <- function(...) invisible(findPackage(..., display="console", return.df=TRUE))
fp <- function(..., display="console", return.df=TRUE) packagefinder::fp(...,display=display, return.df=return.df)
```

The *formals()* method I could **not** get to work.

```r
# Fail-1
formals(fp) <- alist(... = , display="console", return.df=TRUE)

# Fail-2
MY_ARGS <- list(display="console", return.df=TRUE)
formals(fp)[names(MY_ARGS)] <- MY_ARGS
```

---

Other related posts on this:

- [R: Passing function arguments to override defaults of inner functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602407/r-passing-function-arguments-to-override-defaults-of-inner-functions)
- [Setting Function Defaults R on a Project Specific Basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073912/setting-function-defaults-r-on-a-project-specific-basis)
- [Change a function's default argument for all calls within a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416909/change-a-functions-default-argument-for-all-calls-within-a-scope)
- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/formals