# R: Passing function arguments to override defaults of inner functions

Tags: r, function, overriding, defaults

In R, I would like to do something like this:
I have a function f1, that has an argument with a default value; k=3.

```
f1 = function(x,k=3){
    u=x^2+k
    u
}
```

I then later define a second function, f2 that calls f1.

```
f2 = function(z,s){
    s*f1(z)
}
```

What's the cleanest way to allow users of f2 to override the default value of k in the inner function f1?  One trivial solution is to redefine f2 as:

```
f2 = function(z,s,K){
    s*f1(z,K)
}
```

However, I feel this might be cumbersome if I'm dealing with a large heirarchy of functions.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to deal with this is using the `...` argument. This allows you to pass any number of additional arguments to other functions:

```
f1 = function(x,k=3){
    u=x^2+k
    u
}

f2 = function(z,s, ...){
    s*f1(z, ...)
}
```

You'll see this commonly used in functions which call others with many optional arguments, for example `plot`.

Comment: More information [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Reserved.html) and [there](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-three-dots-argument)