# Change a function's default argument for all calls within a scope

Tags: r

Suppose you want to change the default values of the arguments of 
 a function (to fix ideas let's use `dnorm`) from `mean=0,sd=1` to  `mean=pi,sd=pi` within the scope of another function `foo`.

You could do:

```
T_par<-list(mean=pi,sd=pi)
x=3
do.call(dnorm,c(list(x),T_par))
```

but in practice I find that in my application the overhead 
 of using `do.call` is too high.

What I would like to do is to create a function `my_dnorm` that 
 would be a copy of `dnorm` except for the default values of the 
 argument which would be set according `T_par` and just call 
 `my_dnorm` instead of `do.call(dnorm,c(list(x),T_par))`. How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the defaults of a function:

```
mydnorm <- dnorm
formals(mydnorm)$mean <- 2
> mydnorm
function (x, mean = 2, sd = 1, log = FALSE) 
.External(C_dnorm, x, mean, sd, log)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So using your list:

```
T_par<-list(mean=7,sd=10)
mydnorm <- dnorm
formals(mydnorm)[names(T_par)] <- T_par
mydnorm
> mydnorm
function (x, mean = 7, sd = 10, log = FALSE) 
  .External(C_dnorm, x, mean, sd, log)
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Comment: Awesome! I searched so much for this and it was right there!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when there are aliased functions. For example, when using `fp()` instead of `findPackage()` of the `packagefinder` library.